# bitcoin random key

Tags: blockchain.info, random

```
$blockchain_receive_root = "https://api.blockchain.info/";
$mysite_root = "mysite url";
$secret = "CHANGE_TO_RANDOM_SECRET";
$my_xpub = "CHANGE_TO_XPUB_KEY";
$my_api_key = "CHANGE_TO_API_KEY";
```

I have api key and xpub key but how to set the random secert key

Answer (score 0):

The secret can be anything you want it to be. It's intended to prevent malicious users from running your callback URL manually.

Your callback will do a check similar to:

```
if ($secret !== "mycoolsecret") { die (); }
```